# batch download of pictures from picasaweb?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

How can I batch download a bunch of pictures from picasaweb in Linux? I would like to be able to ask for a bunch of photos uploaded in a given time frame to be downloaded in a given directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86452/how-would-i-install-picasa-3-9) answer to install Picasa on your Linux system. The Picasa program allows for bulk downloading.

Comment: It seems this works for picasa 3.0.5744-02, which is the current one with Linux support. It creates a folder in `~/Pictures/Downloaded Albums/`, which is what I was looking for. Thanks!